# Server-side user verification with AWS Cognito user pool via MFA verification code (without password)

Tags: node.js, nestjs, amazon-cognito, server-side, aws-userpools

On the server side using NodeJS + NestJS, TS: 4.7.4, "aws-sdk": "^2.1138.0".
Trying to send a request to AWS Cognito, to obtain a verification code on mobile phone.
It's far away from achieving SMS quota.

An example of my method from the service:

```js
    async sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber: string) {
    const params = {
      AuthFlow: 'USER_SRP_AUTH',
      ClientId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
      // UserPoolId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL,
      AuthParameters: {
        USERNAME: phoneNumber,
        SRP_A: generateSRPA(),
      },
    };
    console.debug('=========== params: ', params);
    try {
      const result = await this.cognitoIdentityServiceProvider
        .initiateAuth(params)
        .promise();
      console.log('=========== result: ', result);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        console.debug('=========== Error: ', error.message);
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }
```

example of generation SRP_A:

```js
const N_HEX ='EEAF0AB9ADB38DD69C33F80AFA...';
export function generateSRPA() {
  const random = randomBytes(32);
  const randomHex = random.toString('hex');
  const srpA = createHash('sha256').update(randomHex).digest('hex');
  return createHash('sha256').update(srpA).update(N_HEX).digest('hex');
}
```

Now requests are successfully sending to AWS and getting response:

```js
=========== result:  {
  ChallengeName: 'PASSWORD_VERIFIER',
  ChallengeParameters: {
    SALT: '4e9b...',
    SECRET_BLOCK: '4x1k...',
    SRP_B: '161d...',
    USERNAME: 'b1d9...',
    USER_ID_FOR_SRP: 'b1d9...'
  }
}
```

But I'm not receiving verification code on my phone.
In the same time with the same user pool and same mobile phone all the flow works fine on mobile app which is connected to Cognito.

Comment: What you can do is add a [CloudWatch for SMS deliveries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html#sns-viewing-cloudwatch-logs) to see why the SMS is failing to deliver. You won't be able to see past failed events, so you'll have to run your app again. You can also bypass Amazon Cognito for a test and [just send a test SMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html). Let me know if you learn anything new from this.